# Controls with TemplateSelector property

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

Now I have ListView and in one column has:

`<GridViewColumn CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource messagerEditorTemplateSelector}"/>`

And everything is fine: cell is filled with content based on item. But now I want to place in this cell 2 controls: for one template must be selected based on binding and other is control with name, say `TimeRangeView`. But I cannot understand how it can be implemented? So I must have code like:

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <SomeControlWhichSupportTemplateSelector ... />
            <views:TimeRangeView ... />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>`
```

Which control should I use for template? I've found only listbox but it must be bound to collection. Of course, I could bind like:

`<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Converter=ItemToCollectionConverter}" />`

but it doesn't look elegant. May be there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a ContentControl and set its ContentTemplateSelector property:

```
 <GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource messagerEditorTemplateSelector}" />
                <views:TimeRangeView ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
```

Note that for Binding to work within your ContentControl, you will have to set the `Content` property to whichever object is used in the Bindings of the DataTemplate returned by your selector.

So that's for option 1.
You can also just use DataTriggers:

```
     <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                  <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyBoundObject}">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyBoundObject.ABooleanProperty}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource myFirstTemplate}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyBoundObject.ABooleanProperty}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource mySecondTemplate}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
                <views:TimeRangeView ... />
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
```

Which is what i do and it works like a charm =)

Comment: Thanks, mate! Thats what I need.
As for second option - thanks for information, but I prefer converters. In my case I am selecting template based on type of bound object so I think this better be done not in XAML.